# Is it possible to disable publish without disabling publishLocal in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I have an `sbt` project where `docker:publishLocal` will create a docker image on my machine for testing, and `docker:publish` will publish the image to a repository and also publish jar files from the build to a repository.

If my project is a snapshot, I would like to disable publishing to the repositories, while still being able to build the local image.

```
ThisBuild / publishArtifact := ! isSnapshot.value
```

does the right thing for the `publish` command, but it also disables `publishLocal`.

I want to write something like

```
if (isSnapshot.value) {
    publish := { }
}
```

but that gives me an error that I do not understand at all:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/dev/project
/Users/dev/build.sbt:1: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: sbt.internal.DslEntry
if (isSnapshot.value) {
^
```

Past experience dictates that redefining `publish` to conditionally call the original version won't work, as

```
publish := {
    if (!isSnapshot.value) publish.value
}
```

gives warnings that the task is always evaluated.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code is that it evaluates `publish.value` regardless of the `if` structure. I recommend reading the documentation on [task dependencies](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Task-Graph.html). If you want to "delay" the evaluation of a task in one of the `if` branches, you need to use [dynamic task](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Dynamic-Task.html) definition:

```
publish := Def.taskDyn {
    if (isSnapshot.value) 
      Def.task {} // doing nothing
    else
      Def.task { publish.value } // could be written as just publish
}.value
```

But apart from fixing your code, you should be aware that there is a special setting for the functionality you want, it's called [`skip`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Publishing.html#Skipping+Publishing):

```
publish/skip := isSnapshot.value
```

Another thing to notice, is the [scoping](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Scopes.html). If you want to override `docker:publish`, which is the same as `Docker/publish` in the new syntax, you should add this `Docker/` scope prefix to every mention of `publish` in the code above.

Comment: Are `publish/skip` and `publishLocal/skip` different values, that do what I hope?

Comment: Yes, they are different. `skip` is a setting, when you write `publish/skip`, you scope it by the `publish` task, so only that task is supposed to take it into account. I never used it with `publishLocal`, but I would expect it to work the same way. Try it.